# How is wscript locating proxy

Tags: vbscript, proxy, scheduled-tasks

This is a little outside my area so would like some advice.  We have a process running internally on a win 2008R2 server which is fired via Windows Scheduled Task (WST) hourly.  The WST runs a .bat file which calls a .vbs file.  This file connects to a public web service, it traverses the XML and inserts it into a database internally.  Job done.

When I built this process it failed to read the XML, no error, it just failed to read the XML, it was like there was nothing to read.   But if you hit the URL direct it would return XML as expected (Note - All traffic from internal to external goes via a proxy.). So I placed it on a public server and it works so nothing wrong with the code.   So we thought ask the firewall team to create a IP forwarder rule.  Eventually we get notified that the rule is in place.   Their last instruction was to add the URL/IP to the host file.   Before I did this I thought to run the code again, now its works.  I would like to know why?

The firewall guys claim that this .vbs code is in fact going via the proxy server.  I wonder whats changed, if this is the case why didn't it work when I first tried it?  Nothing has changed on our win 2008R2 server, nor the .vbs code.  How does the .vbs code find the proxy anyway?   Here is the relevant code from the vbs file:

```
Set objxml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objxml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objXML.async =  False
objXML.Load url
```

and here is an extract from the logs from the firewall guys:

```
[21/Oct/2015:00:16:04 +0000] "" 172.21.64.135 54.206.112.125 407 "GET http://aURLHere.com.au/?lt=aploc&lf=BAYER-CAN&locdet=2&locdet=1&pdf=twc(period=1,point_interval=1,detail=2)&u=13628-1720&k=35a4c2eb6c1b938f388b3ac9124ae85d HTTP/1.1" "" "-" "" 5667 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)" "" "0" 491 "AUTHENTICATION"

[21/Oct/2015:00:16:04 +0000] "" 172.21.64.135 54.206.112.125 407 "GET http://aURLHere.com.au/?lt=aploc&lf=BAYER-CAN&locdet=2&locdet=1&pdf=twc(period=1,point_interval=1,detail=2)&u=13628-1720&k=35a4c2eb6c1b938f388b3ac9124ae85d HTTP/1.1" "" "-" "" 5678 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)" "" "0" 575 "AUTHENTICATION"
```

I would like an explanation for this.  There are too many grey areas for this code to go into production. A mission critical application depends on this code hitting the Web Service hourly.

Edited:

The link in the comment below and this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384075(v=vs.85).aspx

does explain it.  It very complicated to be honest.  The key terms to research on this are WinINet and WinHTTP

Comment: Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could help you

Comment: Thank you for your link.  This and the link I have now included i my post mostly explain it